# Get Number of records in one table related to another

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a `tableA` and a `tableB` with various columns and there is a date column in both A and B.

That date means different things in both, but I want to know (plain English query)

"How many records in tableB are such that their date column (dateField_B) is after that in a tableA-dateField_A.

**TableA**:

```
id_a, a1, a2, a3, ..,dateField_A
```

**TableB**:

```
id_b, b1, b2, b3, ..,dateField_B
```

The difficulty I am having, is that it is a part of large procedure, in which I step-by-step create a large dataset, utilizing various Join.  And the 'resulting number of records' has to be a number in a subset, available for other parts of the routine for comparisons.

Something like

```
case o.numberOfRecords
    when > 5:  <doSomething>
    when 1: <do something other>
    else: <do else>
end as "someField"
```

Answer (score 0):

One method is `cross apply` or a correlated subquery:

```
select a.*, b.cnt
from a cross apply
     (select count(*) as cnt
      from b
      where b.id = a.id and b.dateField_B > a.dateField_A
     ) b;
```

I wouldn't be surprised if you wanted an equality comparison as well, say on `id` (I added it in), but that is not mentioned in your question.

Comment: Thank you.  Yes, I intend the joining on id fields,